# TO_DATE yy,yyyy gives me different results

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

If I run the below queries

> select to_char( TO_DATE(SYSDATE-7,'DD/MM/YY') ,'year') from dual

The result is twenty seventeen

> select to_char( TO_DATE(SYSDATE-7,'DD/MM/YYYY') ,'year') from dual

The result is seventeen

why don't I get twenty seventeen for the second query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are doing an unnecessary explicit conversion from string to date, which is doing an *implicit* conversion from date to string based on your NLS settings.

What you should be doing is just:

```
select to_char(sysdate - 7, 'year') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-7,'YEAR')                 
------------------------------------------
twenty seventeen
```

Because `sysdate-7` is already a date, you should not be calling `to_date()` around that, with any format. As the `to_date()` function takes a string argument, your `sysdate-7` expression has to be implicitly converted to a string first. So you are really doing:

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(sysdate - 7), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'year') from dual;
```

which is using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT value for the implicit inner `to_char()` call, so if that is say `'DD-MON-RR'` you're actually doing:

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(sysdate - 7, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'year') from dual;
```

To see what's going on in there you need to see what the full generated date is, so for that I'm going to change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the session to show the full year:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD';

select sysdate - 7 as raw_date,
  to_char(sysdate - 7, 'DD-MON-RR') as implicit_string,
  to_date(to_char(sysdate - 7, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'DD/MM/YY') as implcit_yy,
  to_date(to_char(sysdate - 7, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as implcit_yyyy
from dual;

RAW_DATE    IMPLICIT_STRING    IMPLCIT_YY  IMPLCIT_YYY
----------- ------------------ ----------- -----------
 2017-04-30 30-APR-17           2017-04-30  0017-04-30
```

Notice the different years in the last two values. [The documentation has a section on format model matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Format-Models.htm#SQLRF51092). The string you are implicitly creating in the middle has a 2-digit year. When you convert the string `'30-APR-17'` back to a date using a `YY` model, it 'helpfully' assumes the current century, so the date ends up as 2017. But when you convert the same string using a `YYYY` model it thinks you really meant the value you passed in and so doesn't assume a century - and you passed it 17, so you end up with the year 17; that is, 0017 and not 2017. (You would also have got the answer you expected using `RRRR`, but it is much better to stick to `YYYY` and actually use 4-digit years everywhere - *if* you actually need to use a string at all.)

Essentially: don't rely on NLS settings or implicit conversions of dates to strings or vice versa.

In this case you don't need *any* conversions, so use the simpler statement at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you should get 2017 for second query, not for the 1 query. Other possibility is NLS settings or session, software settings.
Apart from that you have to use 'YYYY' instead of 'YY' to get 2017