# when I'm using SQL Navigator my query is working but when I call from frontend my query returns 0

Tags: sql, oracle11g, jersey-client

when I'm using SQL Navigator my query is working but when I call from frontend my query returns 0

This my query:

```sql
select * 
from (
  select nvl(b.income,0) as income, a.curDate as curDate, nvl(c.outlay,0) as outlay 
  from (
    select to_char(sysdate-l_day,'DD.MM.YYYY') as curDate,
           to_number(to_char(sysdate-l_day,'yyyymmdd')) as range_period
    from (
      select column_value as l_day 
      from table(sys.odcinumberlist(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14))
    ) 
    order by l_day desc
) a
  left join (
    select to_number(to_char(created_date,'yyyymmdd')) as range_period,
           sum(summa) as income
    from factory_plats
    where status=1 and factories_id = #{factories_id}
      and created_date between to_date (sysdate-20,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date (sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1 - 1 /24/60/60
    group by to_number(to_char(created_date,'yyyymmdd'))
  ) b on a.range_period = b.range_period
  left join (
    select to_number(to_char(ci.created_date,'yyyymmdd')) as range_period,
           sum(summa) as outlay,
           f.factories_id as factories_id
    from card_inputs ci
      left join filials f on ci.filials_id = f.id
    where ci.status=1 and f.factories_id = #{factories_id}
      and ci.created_date between to_date (sysdate-20,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date (sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1 - 1 /24/60/60
    group by to_number(to_char(ci.created_date,'yyyymmdd')), f.factories_id
  ) c on a.range_period = c.range_period
)
```

This query is working SQL Navigator, but when I call from frontend returns 0

Comment: In most of the cases this is caused by the code connecting to a different database or schema then you use in your SQL client

Comment: Show us the frontend code, too.

Comment: I use Jersey web service and my batis which is to connecting my database

Comment: there I call this query List<FactoryInfosBean> items = sqlSession.selectList("selectFactoryPlatInfos", m);

Comment: This is often also caused by uncommitted data. But here the `to_date (sysdate-20,'dd.mm.yyyy')` looks suspicious, that should simply be `sysdate-20` or perhaps `trunc(sysdate-20)`. I suspect [your NLS settings are giving you the wrong century](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829714/266304) - what is `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to in your front end? Same with `to_date (sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy')`, probably should be `trunc(sysdate)`.